# expression engine 2.7 channel form tag captcha isn’t working

Tags: channel-form, captcha

I have 2 forms that are using the channel form tag, not Freeform, and the CAPTCHA isn’t working. I have made sure all of the preferences have been addressed and that all paths to any images are correct. I AM using a Freeform submission form on another page and the CAPTCHA works fine with the Freeform tag. Does anyone happen to have the same issue and can anyone help me find documentation on why the channel form tag isn’t displaying the CAPTCHA?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I simply removed the {if captcha} and {/if} and it showed up. I tested it on desktop and mobile. I also made sure I got an error if all the fields were not filled out. It was the one thing I didn't try.

Our form is creating an entry in a testimonials channel and then outputting on the testimonials page. I have no idea why the example from the EE User Guide did not work but if you ever find yourself in this same scenario try this and it may work :)

([CAPTCHA DOCUMENTATION PAGE](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/security/captchas.html))

Answer (score 2):

Are you logged in while viewing the form? Native EE CAPTCHAs don't display for Super Administrators.

Comment: I am not logged in while looking at the page containing the CAPTCHA. I have it in the template but it does not display in the page at all, not even in the source. I am using Chrome, Safari and FF as my browsers. Doesn't show in any of them. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Better: Not logged in on the browser where I am testing. I set up the permissions correctly in another browser, where I am logged in, but still not seeing CAPTCHA with channel form tag.

 {if captcha}
    <p>Please enter the word you see in the image below:</p>
    <p>{captcha}<br /> <input type="text" name="captcha" value="{captcha_word}" size="20" maxlength="20"  /></p>
{/if}  

Once the form is filled out and submitted it creates an entry in a testimonials channel and outputs the information on the testimonials page. The client is receiving quite a bit of spam so this is becoming a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same issue, make sure that you go to Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Form and then choose Yes for Guest Captcha for the relevant channel.